# Electron check if a window is already open and close before creating

Tags: windows, electron, destroy

Is it possible to detect in electron if window is already created and close before creating another one?

here is my sample code

```
// video window listener
ipcMain.on("load-video-window", (event, data) => {
  // create the window

  //window.close() if window exist;

  let videoPlayer = new BrowserWindow({
    show: true,
    width: 840,
    height: 622,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      plugins: true,
    },
  });

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    videoPlayer.loadURL(
      process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL + "video_player.html"
    );
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) videoPlayer.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    videoPlayer.loadURL(`app://./video_player`);
  }

  videoPlayer.on("closed", () => {
    videoPlayer = null;
  });

  // here we can send the data to the new window
  videoPlayer.webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
    videoPlayer.webContents.send("data", data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work

```
let playerWindow;
ipcMain.on("load-video-window", (event, data) => {

  if (playerWindow) {
    playerWindow.close();
  }

  playerWindow = new BrowserWindow();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for Feedback, closing the window works like that, but on new open I get an error `Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'webContents' of null`

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Lord Midi code, we can check to see if a window is not destroyed and is still focusable. You can do that with the following code:

```
let playerWindow;
const isPlayerWindowOpened = () => !playerWindow?.isDestroyed() && playerWindow?.isFocusable();

ipcMain.on("load-video-window", (event, data) => {

  if (isPlayerWindowOpened()) {
    playerWindow.close();
  }

  playerWindow = new BrowserWindow();

})
```

Comment: To make sure you're addressing the core question, can you update your answer to also include how to apply this code to close the window if it's already opened? I realize that's a trivial extension of what you've written here, which addresses the core challenge. But as that's part of the question, it will be useful to demonstrate the implementation.